# Bad order of my array in a double angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a Json data from a mongodb database collection.

I managed to display the keys of this json.

Now, I'm trying to display an array in a table by a double ng-repeat in my 
view.

I have got nearly what i want, but the value order is incorrect.

If I use the attribute names of my items it's good but I don't want that.

I use this code in my view :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<caption>Content</caption>

<thead>
    <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="caption in captions">
    {{caption}}
    </th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="content in contentCollection">
<td ng-repeat="item in content">
{{item}}
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

will display:

```
_id     session     expires

id1         expires1        session1
```

It should be:

```
_id     session     expires

id1     session1    expires1
```

I send an array from my controller with the right value order (id1, session1, expires1). I can see it in the Chrome console with a `console.log()`.

I think I have to do a directive to get a workaround but maybe I missed something.

Do you have an idea on what is wrong ?

Thanks,

Rom

Comment: create a plunk or a fiddle with sample json data to make it clearer what you're after

Answer (score 0):

In an ng-repeat if you want to ensure an order you'll want to use the orderby filter http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy. You should not need a directive but may need a custom comparator for your filter if you need advanced ordering.

If your array is just a list of strings then you'll need a custom filter such as:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .filter('mySort', function() {
        return function(list) {
            return list.sort();
        }
    });
```

However given your view I'd assume you have an object and your just pulling the pieces and pre-normalizing for this repeat set. If that's the case you'll want to do something more like the code at http://plnkr.co/edit/ART87TjilotbnsuD02y1?p=preview.

*Note: that you'll want to move the array into a service and have the service also return the keys.*

Lastly you might consider moving this whole table into a directive to better parse the pieces of your object if your going to be repeating this process.